# VFP - FoxPro - Textbox: how to distinguish between empty input and 0 input

Tags: null, textbox, visual-foxpro, is-empty

I'm maintaining a legacy VFP application.

There is a textbox for numeric input.
In the validate event I want to check if the user entered a number or left the textbox empty.

How can I detect if the user left the field with no characters/numbers in it?

Unfortunately I cannot distinguish if the user entered a 0 or completely deleted the characters in the textbox. This.Value is 0 in both cases and VARTYPE(This.Value) is "N" and EMPTY(This.Value) is .T.

Background: later really entered numbers should go as the number to the database whereas a deleted input field should be stored as .NULL. (yes the corresponding table column accepts Null-values)

Comment: @theTinMan, being bare doesn't mean it is not an answer. This question needed a simple bare answer.  Even those dots at the end were not needed but added to fill the required length as a message. You should never be rude enough to delete someone else's post especially when you don't have an idea about the programming language the question is subject to. It doesn't need to explain why it is an answer when it is obvious why it is an answer. Anyone who use VFP more than a week is educated enough to see that it is an answer. Why would you think the OP is uneducated about VFP as much as you are?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if the TextBox is bound to the table column (i.e. ControlSource = mytable.myfield) but I'll assume it is.

I don't think you will be able to do this if the TextBox is bound to the column. You will have to unbind it, and handle populating it on record navigation etc manually.

You can then check as follows:

In the TextBox Init() method:

```
this.NullDisplay = ''
return .t.
```

In the Valid() method:

```
Local llReturn

    * -- In case it's a subclassed TextBox
    llReturn = DoDefault()

    * -- Assumes that the record pointer is on the right record in the table!

    If llReturn 
        If alltrim(this.Text) == ""
            replace myfield with .null. in mytable
        Else
            replace myfield with Val(this.Text) in mytable
        endif   
    EndIf

Return llReturn
```

Comment: Quite a good solution, but 10% to optimal are missing.  If the user enters 0 into the textbox, the textbox is cleared and .NULL. is stored to the table.   The goal to distinguish between 0 (a number that is zero) and .NULL. (= empty input) is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. 'alltrim(this.Text) == ""' is never working as the fiel is bound to an integer field in the DB, so it is always type numeric, not character. When the user clears the field manually the Value is 0 not an empty string.

Comment: As the answer says, do not bind the textbox to anything.